# Converting string date to Human Readable Format HRF (Stata)

Tags: date, format, stata

version: stata15

Date (format %9s), type 8s - 20171230

```
date
20171230
20171230
```

I want to be able to see 30dec2017,

```
gen newdate = date(date, "YMD")
format newdate %td 
list
```

here is what I see

```
date       newdate 
20171230    .
```

Why do I see a missing data in the new date variable? what am I doing wrong in the `newdate %td` command ?

Comment: You often ignore comments and answers to your questions. You should please (a) accept previous answers that were correct and (b) reply to open queries before you can (reasonably) expect further help.

Comment: Downvoted and voted to close. Very confused and confusing. No real sign that you are a professional or enthusiast programmer even trying to provide clear questions based on reproducible examples in the recommended manner. You should study `help dataex` in Stata (or `search dataex` if that doesn't work) and here on SO you should study https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The link above was given to you in an earlier comment.

Comment: Still not using `dataex`.

Comment: Retracted close vote. An answer is possible, although I have no idea why you are getting a result I can't reproduce.

Answer (score 2):

ANSWER TO ORIGINAL QUESTION:

This makes no obvious sense to me. Questions like this waste your time as well.

You don't give a clear reproducible example of your data. In a recent version of Stata, `help dataex` tells you how to do that. If you're using an older version of Stata then you should be telling us that.

1. Your first sentence seems to be telling us that you have a string variable `date` with storage type `str8` and display format `%9s`.
2. If that is so, then `tostring` is pointless, as you already have a string variable.
3. The statement `gen date = date(date, "YMD")` is illegal, as `date` already exists as a variable. If you typed that, it will not have worked. If you typed something else, you should tell us.
4. The format `%td` should give you a fairly readable date. So, you've already answered your own question. If you have a numeric date variable, read `help datetime display formats` to learn more.

EDIT The fact that most of the above is irrelevant to the real question shows how you wasted time not asking the real question.

ANSWER TO MODIFIED QUESTION:

I can't reproduce your problem. You report a missing date result, and clearly no kind of display format will make sense of that. But Stata 15.1 does this for me. So, something is wrong with what you are telling us. Perhaps your Stata is corrupted, or something else is not as you say.

```
clear 
set obs 1 
gen str8 date = "20171230"
gen newdate = daily(date, "YMD") 

list 

     +--------------------+
     |     date   newdate |
     |--------------------|
  1. | 20171230     21183 |
     +--------------------+
```

21183 will show nicely with a `%td` format. Using `daily()` rather than `date()` is irrelevant, as the same result is yielded by `date()`.